# Find All Divs having same data in a Div

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

Want to get both elements having `data-id=1` inside parent div#tabs

```
<div id="tabs">
        <div id="cars">
         <div data-id="1">Yes</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bikes">
         <div data-id="1">No</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: var y=$('div#tabs').find("*[data-id='1']").html();

Comment: its only returning first div html that is "Yes"

Comment: Please update your question text with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#tabs').find('[data-id=1]')
```